# PHP 502 Server Error: Problems with code or server?

Tags: php, web-server, 502-error

Not sure if this is the right forum, but I'm hoping someone can help me.

We had a web app running on our web server for a while now. Suddenly it stopped working and displays a 502 error - `Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server`.

I have never seen this type of error and I have no Idea how to work it (I'm just an entry level programmer). I did manage to get the DB and the original code and they work fine on a local environment.

Comment: Start by checking web server logs

Answer (score 0):

502 is a HTTP code. That means temporary unavailable. Is the web server still running? Check the web server logs